# MySQL - how to remove unmatch record

Tags: mysql

Looking for query, remove all record of child table where parent id not match with master record.

**Master-Table**

```
 1. David
 2. Fin
 3. Lisa
```

**Child-Table**

```
 1. 100
 1. 200
 2. 200
 2. 222
 8. 100
 9. 100
```

Output Required on **Child Table**

```
 1. 100
 1. 200
 2. 200
 2. 222
```

**want to remove record # 8 and 9 from child table, cuz it doesn't have parent id.**

Thanks

Comment: exactly how does the master table relate to the child table? Right now you've got some apples and some oranges, and are asking for a pipe wrench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an outer join in a `DELETE` operation:

```
DELETE a 
FROM child a
LEFT JOIN master b ON a.parent_id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

To prevent the need to do this, what you should look into are [Referential CASCADE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) actions that execute whenever you delete a parent (row in the master table).

If you have an `ON DELETE CASCADE` set up on the foreign key in your child table, any parent that gets deleted will ***also*** have all of its corresponding "children" deleted as well.